# Tell Google Test to resume executing the rest of the tests after a crashed test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a large unit test suite written in C++ using Google Test.

I have recently made a change to the codebase which may affect different parts of the system, so various tests should now probably fail or even crash. I would like to run once the entire suite (which unfortunately takes a long time to complete), summarize the list of the failed tests, and fix them one by one.

However, when ever a test crashes (e.g. with a segmentation fault) as opposed to simply logically failing, it seems that GTest stops and executes no more tests.

I can than fix the crashed test, however rerunning the entire suite will take a long time.

Is there a way to tell GTest to resume executing the rest of the tests after a test has crashed?

Or, alternatively, at least a way to launch GTest starting from a particular test (assuming the order of the tests is always the same)?

Answer (score 3):

1. If you are are need to test if assertion is triggered when API is used incorrectly then gtest delivers something called [DEATH TEST](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#death-tests).
2. If your test crashed because of Segmentation Fault you should fix this ASAP! You can disable test temporary by adding `DISABLED_` prefix, or by adding `GTEST_SKIP()` in test boy. Alternatively there is also command line argument `--gtest_filter=<colon separated positive patterns>[:-<colon separated negative patterns>]`. There is no way to recover from segmentation fault, so test suite can't continue.
3. If you use gcc or clang (msvc has this feature experimentally) you can enable address sanitizer to quickly detect all memory issues in your tested code. You will able to faster fix those issues.
4. There are cool plugins to IDE to handle gtest, those should you help you track which test were run, which failed and which crashed.

Answer (score 1):

Google tests are not able to do what you need. I'd suggest you write a simple test runner that:

1. Runs the test executable with --gtest_list_tests to get a list of all tests.
2. Runs a loop thru all tests that prints out the test number and runs the test executable with --gtest_filter=FooTest.Bar to invoke only one test in each loop iteration.
3. The loop skips the required number of iterations and runs from the number N after the test with the number N is fixed.

You only need to write such a runner script once, and it shouldn't be hard.